# Error when using path with consecutive dots in concat file of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

A user of my software encountered a crash when trying to concatenate files that were in a directory with triple dots in its name. I can also reproduce the problem with double dots. Lines in the concat file look something like:

> file 'C:\a...b\video.MP4'

ffmpeg crashes with

> [concat @ 0000025dbde52e00] Impossible to open 'b\video.MP4'

So it seems like consecutive dots break the path in some way. I could not find info on them being a special character.

I tried escaping the dots in different ways, and the one I expected to work was

> file 'C:\a'\.\.\.'b\video.MP4'

But made no progress.

What am I missing?

Edit: I wonder if it's interpreting the dots as part of a relative path

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it was related to ffmpeg understanding that those were relative paths. This solves it (I have yet to test it on macOS)

> file 'file:C:\a...b\video.MP4'

Comment: it also work on mac